# Notepad++ восстановить расстановку переносов строк в тегах

Tags: html, notepad++

Имеется такой файл:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно получить такой:

[image: результатт]

Замена `>` на `>\r\n` не помогает: убираются переносы там, где не надо.

Comment: А как они должны переноситься?

Comment: Вот так:
http://i.shotnes.com/u/2242/0731/screenshot_11478.png

Answer (score 1):

Явно этот файл был подготовлен в какой-то программе, которая сделала такие файлы. Вам по-хорошему нужно разбираться именно с этой программой, её настройками перевода строк.

Если же нужно быстрое решение -- то можете воспользоваться следующим рецептом.

Нажмите в документе `Crtl+H` чтобы перейти в режим замены текста.

Заменяем в тексте следующее вхождение: `name>\r\n`

Заменяем на: `name>`

И аналогично с остальными тегами(version, modifiedBy, desc и т.п.), наверное их не так и много будет в структурированном xml.

Важно: `Search Mode` должен быть `Extended`

А тот вариант что вы пробуете много лишних тегов вырезает. Понимаю желание обойтись одной-единственной заменой, но увы.

PS Хотя нет. Сделайте две замены. Сначала ту, которую вы делали (`>\r\n` -> `>`), а потом `><` на `>\r\n<`. Форматирование поедет слегка (отступы), но в целом будет читаемее.

PPS И совсем простой вариант. Скопируйте весь текст в какую-либо программу, которая авторматически форматирует xml -- например, в Visual Studio. :) Если есть файл с расширением xml -- то при вставке в него студия заново форматирует весь вставляемый текст. Наверное, есть и другие программы.

PPPS Ещё. Сам не пробовал, но [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961217/how-to-format-xml-in-notepad) советуют поставить плагин в Notepad++ для форматирования XML. Плагин называется `Pretty Print (libXML)`, хоткей простой - `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + B`

Comment: Вроде регулярку тут не подобрать удачную, чтобы обойтись одной заменой. Замена `>$` съест лишние теги, по примеру видно.